# Why I cannot use upgraded plotly in Google Colab?

Tags: python, plot, plotly, google-colaboratory

I just cannot use the newest version of plotly in the GoogleColab even though I have upgraded.

```
! pip install plotly --upgrade

import plotly
plotly.__version__
```

I tried this and got results like that:

Requirement already up-to-date: plotly in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (4.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: retrying>=1.3.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from plotly) (1.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from plotly) (1.15.0)

4.4.1

I tried to use plotly in Jupyter Notebook and it worked, so I must have successfully install the newest version, but how? Why it's not in the Google Colab? I am so confused that why it still shows 4.4.1 not 4.13.0.

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 2):

`usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (4.13.0)` This not from colab.

If you run this `pip install plotly --upgrade` in colab. It will update the colab's version.

Comment: Hi, thanks for help! (4.13.0)  is the result after I run the pip command in colab, I am also confused about this.

Comment: Oh, I have figured out I forgot to restart the runtime